# License change in Affero licensed software

Tags: agpl-3.0, ownership

Some time ago I published the source code for a web application under the GNU AFFERO license, some people forked it and modified it in different ways.

Now I would like to modify the original version of the software, the one I published initially which only includes my own work, but I don't want to share the modifications. Is this compatible with the AFFERO license or am I obligated to publish the changes under the same license?

Comment: If you are the copyright holder, you can publish the new version under whatever licence you like as long as the original version remains available under the original terms.

Comment: Thanks james, that's what I though, but I wasn't sure if it was the case for the Affero license too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to do what you want with your own software. You can take it fully closed, whatever.

Copyright is based on the idea given above, and that the owner is entitled to allow others to do something (copying, creating derivative works, ...) that is forbidden otherwise. This is a *license* (fancy legalese for "allow"). You can allow others just because you want to (BSD style licenses) or place some restrictions (GPL doesn't allow to pass only derivatives like binaries, Microsoft gives out some code on condition it can only used on Windows, ...), you can do it for free or ask for payment, ...